# openshift app requires Maven version 3.0.4

Tags: maven, openshift

Is there any way to update the maven installation on a openshift online account? 
The only similar problem to my that I could find was this one https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/is-maven-update-planned, but it was not answered.

So here is the error of my deploy attempt.

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 27.229s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Apr 10 22:47:30 EDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/161M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.flexmojos.oss:flexmojos-maven-plugin:6.0.1:compile-swf
(default-compile-swf) on project isis-client: The plugin net.flexmojos.oss:flexmojos-maven-
plugin:6.0.1 requires Maven version 3.0.4 -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add that to http://openshift.com/ideas and get people to vote on it